Flame-retardant breathable fabric for covering exposed loose fiberglass insulation?
I have some exposed insulation in my basement that I would like to prevent from getting disturbed by boxes on a shelf I'll be accessing right in front of it.  I know that fiberglass insulation can be harmful if disturbed/bumped/etc. and that puts the harmful tiny particles of it into the air.  So, I'm looking for an inexpensive, simple approach to covering it -- but know I need to keep it breathable so that moisture isn't trapped between the outside of the house and this cover, making the insulation wet.
Drywall could work, but is a more involved process than I'm hoping for.  I considered attaching a sheet of plywood, but am not sure if it's vapor-permeable enough.  Then looking things up more and seeing past posts, I wondered about some sort of fabric sheet.  It's easy to find cotton (which is very breathable) such as through Joann Fabrics... but I'm wondering what others recommend as far as fire-retardant cotton or fire-retardant other fabric that could easily be attached to the studs with tack nails, so that the loose fiberglass insulation isn't directly exposed?  I'm imagining something sold in sheets or a roll - but I don't need a ton of it.  Is there a product that's made for this kind of situation - or anything that might work well for this scenario?
Any particular product or brand recommendations would be great!  I've been having a hard time finding products like this.
Or if I'm way off and this is a terrible idea -- say the word!  I'd welcome any feedback, or alternative suggestions :).
Thanks so much!

Are you in a "Primarily Heating" or "Primarily Cooling" climate?

Unfortunately drywall is almost the number one recommended to prevent/slow down flames from getting into walls and going up.  Your local building department will know what is allowed.  There is quite a few studies about flame retardants and their safety to humans.

Welding blanket?

@Ecnerwal - Thanks!  I'm in Massachusetts - so a "primarily heating" climate.

Then your vapor barrier should be on the inside of the insulation. The outside of the house should already be vapor-permeable.
